# Checking existence of row with specific attributes in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with one to many relation, like this:

```
MY_TABLE(ID, VALUE)
MY_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE(ID, MY_TABLE_ID, NAME, VALUE)
```

I want to check if there is record in MY_TABLE with particular attributes.

This query will probably explain what I am doing:

```
select 1 
from MY_TABLE mt
where exists (select 1 
              from MY_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE mta 
              where mta.my_table_id = mt.id
                and (mta.name = 'attributeName1' and mta.value = 'attributeValue1'))
  and exists (select 1 
              from MY_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE mta 
              where mta.my_table_id = mt.id
                and (mta.name = 'attributeName2' and mta.value = 'attributeValue2'))
  and exists ...
.
.
.
```

My question is if there is a better (faster) way to check that existence.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine.  For performance, you want the following index:

```
create index idx_my_table_attribute_3 on my_table_attribute(my_table_id, name, value);
```

In fact, with this index, your code is probably the fastest way to implement this logic in Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for answer, good to know to not looking for something want does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rewrites:

```
    select * from MY_TABLE mt
    where exists (select 1 from MY_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE mta 
                where mta.my_table_id = mt.id
                and(
                    (mta.name = 'attributeName1' and mta.value = 'attributeValue1')
                    OR (mta.name = 'attributeName2' and mta.value = 'attributeValue2')
                    OR ....
    )
```

or

```
    select * from MY_TABLE mt
    where mt.id in (select mta.my_table_id from MY_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE mta 
                where 
                    (mta.name = 'attributeName1' and mta.value = 'attributeValue1')
                    OR (mta.name = 'attributeName2' and mta.value = 'attributeValue2')
                    OR ....
    )
```

An index on (name,value) may help if the cardinality of these columns is very high.

Comment: Thanks for answer, index will definetely help. But your rewrites will querry existence when ANY, not ALL of requested name value attribute exist.

Comment: Mea culpa. If the index is unique, you can have it like this in the inline subquery;
select mta.my_table_id from .... where .... (same as in my answer) group by mta.my_table_id having count(*)=number_of_conditions.
The idea is to have just one on scan of the attributes table, then a hash join with MY_TABLE.